# Remove a div in AMP-Animation on scroll down

Tags: css, frontend, amp-html

Help required from people working on `Google-AMP`.

I am trying to hide a particular part of a div( an item from navbar) while scrolling down.

Let say I need to hide this div.

```
<div id="divToHide">This div is to hide on scroll down. </div>
```

AMP Animation Code:

```
<amp-animation id="hideDiv"
  layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "duration": "200ms",
      "fill": "both",
      "iterations": "1",
      "direction": "alternate",
      "animations": [{
        "selector": "#divToHide",
        "keyframes": [{
          "display": "none"
        }]
      }]
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>
```

AMP position observer code:

```
<amp-position-observer on="enter:hideDiv.start" layout="nodisplay"></amp-position-observer>
```

When I change `display: none` to the following
`"opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden"`.

The div content disappears but still it takes the space. It should not take space as `display: none` does. Help me workout for display none type solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display none is not allowed in keyframes in amp animation.
Although this is not going to work for every case. But anyhow this worked for me.

I moved element out of screen and it seemed as hidden.
Here is the solution.

```
"keyframes": [{
   "transform": "translateY(-80px)"
}]
```

A trick for element somewhere between the viewport you can simply move it on X axis i.e.`100vw`

```
"transform": "translateY(100vw)"
or
"transform": "translateY(200vw)"
```

The second one  is more secure.

Hopes this would help.
Thanks